# Service routing 404 through consul and Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, http-status-code-404, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-consul

I am creating a microservice app with Spring cloud gateway and Consul.
When I try getting a response from the microservice "example" with its port (3000) I get the response.
But When I try to access with the gateway (demo) port (9090) I got the Whitelabel Error Page 404 error.
Please help, thank you.

[WhiteLabel 404 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2KBe.jpg)

[Consul](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxvDC.jpg)

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 9090
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: example
          uri: lb://example
          predicates:
            - Path= /**
    loadbalancer:
      ribbon:
        enabled: true
    consul:
      host: 127.0.0.1
      port: 8500
      discovery:
        health-check-interval: 2s
        health-check-timeout: 2s
        tags: secure=true
        fail-fast: true
        instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${random.value}
  jpa:
    database: mysql
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gatewaypfe?serverTimezone=UTC
    username: root
    password:
  application:
    name: demo
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

Comment: have you tried to access the same service both ways?

Comment: Yes I created another service X and I accessed to the example service through it and it worked.

Comment: Have you tried to intercept the error with an error handler and capture what is going on?

Comment: No. But All works for me when using Zuul

Comment: If I were you, I would add an error handler, launch a bugging session, put a breakpoint in the error handler, then use the gateway.Start with a controller error handler. If the error is happening elsewhere you will find out quickly